# Server Resources for Apple OSX Server

Tags: remote-desktop, mac-osx-server, internal-dns

Looking to find the recommended resource specifications, CPU, RAM, Disk, for running internal DNS and Apple Remote Desktop Task Server within a Mac OS only environment on Mac OSX Server.

As we currently we do not have any "server" level hardware, i.e. Apple MacPro or Dell PowerEdge, my thought is to beef up a couple of older MacBook Pro 2012 models until Apple releases new hardware.

To run an OSX DNS server, for internal/split DNS, on a network with approximately 2,000 clients, what would be necessary amount of RAM? Is 8GB sufficient or do we need more like 16GB? (MBP supports up to 32GB)

Right now all DNS points to an external provider (OpenDNS or Google) and all external traffic would continue to be forwarded.

Same question for the ARD (Apple Remote Desktop Task Server). Is there a sweet spot for the amount of RAM required? We do not plan to do major deployments of packages at this time, but use it in conjunction with the DNS server to manage lists of internal devices for remote connection.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't use OS X for a network with 2000 clients. Without any server grade hardware ever to be released again by Apple, this is just not a viable choice - OS X Server is meant for SOHO operations these days.

Comment: We may move to Windows for DNS in the future, but currently this I'm working with what we have available. The question is not a duplicate as it refers specifically to Mac specific network where the others are more general network planning on a larger scale.